# How To make Days IN domain variable in xml /python/odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

**I want make days  is variable from field in Python code**

```
('date','&gt;=', ((context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=5)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: Can you provide some context? For example what is in `context_today()`, how does your dream output look like, stuff like that. Otherwise you just get downvotes for this.

Comment: context_today() is date of today i want make days= x   x is variable in python.py

Comment: please delete these comments and edit your question

Comment: You do not understand the quest

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


('date','&gt;=', fields.Date.today() + relativedelta(days=5))
```

Comment: i want make value of days  is variable in python.py

Comment: ('date','&gt;=', ((context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=5)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))   this part in domain in xml view